# Is Max (R) a Hausdorff space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, gn.general-topology

I asked the following question at < https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508168/is-max-r-a-hausdorff-space  >, but I pose it here for any help.

> Recall a space is totally disconnected if the only connected subsets are singletons (one-point subsets). Now let $R $ be a commutative ring with identity such that $\operatorname{Max}(R)$ is a totally disconnected space, in the sense of the $Zariski$ topology. I want to know if $\operatorname{Max}(R)$ Hausdorff in this case?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10):

For a ring $R$, the space $\operatorname{MaxSpec} R$ -- the set of maximal ideals of $R$ endowed with the Zariski topology -- has two evident properties: its singleton sets are closed (i.e., the **T1** separation property) and it is quasi-compact.  In [his thesis](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-142-00/S0002-9947-1969-0251026-X/S0002-9947-1969-0251026-X.pdf), M. Hochster showed that conversely any quasi-compact T1 topological space $X$ is homeomorphic to $\operatorname{MaxSpec} R$ for some commutative ring $R$.

A totally disconnected topological space is automatically T1: closures of points are connected sets!  So your question reduces to one of general topology: is there a totally disconnected, quasi-compact non-Hausdorff topological space $X$?  The answer is yes and indeed [Eric Wofsey's answer to your earlier math.stackexchange.com question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507986/is-totally-disconnected-space-hausdorff/1508024#1508024) provides an example.

In summary: **no, not necessarily**.

**Added**: On the other hand, $\operatorname{Spec} R$ -- the set of prime ideals of $R$ endowed with the Zariski topology -- is T1 iff it is Hausdorff iff it is totally disconnected iff $\operatorname{Spec} R = \operatorname{MaxSpec} R$.  See e.g. $\S$13.3 [of these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf).  Maybe this is helpful for you.